# Email Triggered With Success Row count in Target Using informatica

Tags: email, workflow, informatica, informatica-powercenter, rowcount

I need to trigger an email with all the stats like Count of Rows which are successfully loaded in the target, Failed rows count with the help of Informatica Powercenter.
So where can I find this information for the Workflow and how can I used that information to trigger the email to respective people.
There is an email task present in the Informatica which I am hoping I can use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use built-in session parameters to collect session run details, e.g.:

- $PMSessionName: Name of the Informatica session.
- $PMSourceName@TableName: Name of the source table name.
- $PMTargetName@TableName: Name of the target table name.
- $PMSourceQualifierName@numAffectedRows: Number of records returned
  from source.
- $PMTargetName@numAffectedRows: Number of record
  inserted/updated into the target table.
- $PMTargetName@numRejectedRows: Number of records error out in target.

Here's more info: http://powercenternotes.blogspot.com/2014/01/an-etl-framework-for-operational.html

Answer (score 0):

you are right. You can use e mail task. Or you can use post session email command to send mail with statistics - like output file, counts etc.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to trigger an email with all the stats like Count of Rows which are successfully loaded in the target, Failed rows count with the help of Informatica Powercenter.

Since you are looking for session level count, you may want to look into using post-session email and using the [email variables](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-4-0/workflow-basics-guide/sending-email/working-with-post-session-email/email-variables-and-format-tags.html).

> ...trigger the email to respective people. There is an email task present in the Informatica which I am hoping I can use that.

If you need to use email task, in the link going to email task, you can double-click on the link, and set [link condition](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-4-0/workflow-basics-guide/workflows-and-worklets/workflow-links/creating-link-conditions/example-of-link-conditions.html) to trigger which email task to go towards.